# Android updating a database

Tags: android

I there a way I can set up my app so that things like the database and images can be optionally downloaded/updated when when I make changes to the data, without updating the app. i.e. a kind of syncing with the new data?

I would have the database and images on my server and the user can update or not without having an icon on their phone saying there are updates available.

Comment: sounds like you need some kind of server side cache and a hashing scheme to determine whether individual pieces of data need to be updated. you should also differentiate between the application code itself and the data it uses. and you need a policy for determining when data needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Android databases are just sqlite.db files. You should be able to have a button in your app that downloads a new sqlite.db file from your server. Have it replace the file that is already on the device and you should be good to go!

Comment: That’s exactly what I want to do. The database is in the root of the /assets folder, so first thing I need to do is add the button and write the code to download and over write database the existing database and then work on my DatabaseHelper  to update the system database on the device. This would be so much simpler if Android just worked with the database in the /assets folder as is, but that cool.

Comment: The databases are stored in the data/data, and you can copy a file to there programmatically

Comment: it is worth noting that the DatabaseHelper has a method onUpgrade, where you can specify specific behavior for copying over data from old database format to new format

Answer (score 0):

If you have a localized database you can modify, add to, and delete as needed based on server response. Create a robust enough Database Helper and you can use it to make the database whatever is needed, in a run time environment.